# Setting a .bat file to run at windows shutdown doesn't work

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to run a Java application at windows shutdown. I have Windows 7 and I have tried to do this in 2 ways:

1. I have created a .bat file containing the following:

   ```
   javaw -Xmx200m -jar C:\path\to\jar\dl.jar
   ```

   dl.jar is the application I need to run at shutdown and I added in `Local Group Policies->Windows Settings->Scripts(Stratup/Shutdown)->Shutdown->Script Name` my batch file, but it doesn't work.
2. Also I have added in Shutdown Scripts from Local Group Policies at Script Name: `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` and at Script Parameters the path to my batch file, it doesn't work in this way either

If I run the .bat file from command promt it works. Does anyone have any idea how to make this work?

Comment: I would put the batch as the script name, and leave parameter blank since you dont have any..

Comment: I have tried this, it doesn't work...

Comment: If JVM is shut off first, then the file won't run, right?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "it doesn't work", does it run at all or does it give some error?

Comment: i don't have any error, simply, the action from jar, which is to clear a folder is not executed. I have specified that the batch file runs ok if it's from command promt.

Comment: do you know if the bat file is ever executed or not?

Comment: What do you mean when you say ever executed?

Comment: nobody can help me with this issue....????